# JWT token generation in node js api

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jwt

I want to implement JWT token in my API with the sign in of the user I have already created the user in the MongoDB collection and I want to authenticate it by sign-in page as of now I am checking with the POSTMAN but I am not able to generate a one please can someone help

Following is my piece of code : -

1) server.js

const jwt =  require('jsonwebtoken');  //used to create, sign , and verify tokens

```
const logger = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/saddleHorseacademy");
process.env.SECRET_KEY = "SaddleHorseKey";

app.post('/loginUser',(request,response)=>{
var user =  {
   userName : request.body.userName,
   password : request.body.password
}
   userList.findOne({user},function(error,user){
     if(error){
       console.log(error);
       return response.status(500).send("unable to sign in");
     }
     if(!user){
       return response.status(404).send("not user found");
     }
     else{
       var token =  jwt.sign(user,process.env.SECRET_KEY,{
         expiressInMinutes:1440
       });

      return response.json({
        success:true,
        Message:'Check your token!',
        token: token
      });
    }

   })
});
```

When i am trying to hit it with postman by giving format as :-

```
{
    "userName":"mayank_9",
    "password":"saddle09"
}
```

it returns response as not user find but in my db i have data like this

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ac48ba8034cf044c0832ea9"),
        "userName" : "mayank_9",
        "password" : "saddle09",
        "__v" : 0
}
```

please help me stuck with this

Comment: please show the screen shot of postman

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method is using [shorthand assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for the query object ,  `{user}`, which creates the following object:

```
{
  user: {
    userName: 'mayank_9',
    password: 'saddle09'
  }
}
```

Therefore the `find` is trying to match an object with a `user` property that has that object as a value. I assume that is not the structure of the records in your collection so it will not find a match. Passing the object directly will avoid this:

```
 userList.findOne(user, function (err, user) {...});
```

Comment: I tried this but still it says not user found when i tried to debug it userList.findOne(user ) it have username nd password information but eventually after pressing F8 it goes user : null

Comment: @MayankPurohit Which `user`? You use `user` both for the query object and the returned value. Also, query your DB directly with those values to see if it returns a record.

Comment: the user which is return value i have changed the user object to usercredentials and it also started giving error payload should be plain object

Comment: @MayankPurohit As long as the record in the collection looks like the one in your post and the query object matches some of the values then it should return the matched record. Either the query object doesn't match (e.g. typos, encoding issues, etc.) or the wrong collection is being queried against. The original issue of using shorthand assignment was definitely a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
.findOne(user, function() {...});
```

Without the curly brackets.

Comment: Try logging the req.body to check the key /value pairs are correct